# Why not output I hope result in PHP7 using try and catch?

Tags: php, php-7

In PHP7 env, I have the follow code:

```
try {
    echo strlen([123]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error...';
}
```

Because `[123]` is not `string`, I want it to output `error...`, but it outputs:

```
Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Why?

Comment: Because a warning is not an exception, much like how car wheel isn't Jupiter and similar.

Comment: You need to add `declare(strict_types=1);` to the top of your file in order to make this an Error. (You'll have to catch TypeError or Error or Throwable instead of Exception,)

Comment: OK，Thanks Mjh and NikiC. `Can I try/catch a warning? ` have had answers.